# Maven Jacoco: Jacoco:report doesn't pick the configuration from pom.xml

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, reporting, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to separate the generation of jacoco coverage analysis for my unit tests.

I have created (in my pom.xml) a profile specific for it because I don't want to run the tests in all my environments.

This is the the profile section in my pom.xml:

```
<profile>
            <id>unit-tests</id>

            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.SPRING_BOOT_ACTIVE_PROFILE</name>
                    <value>!prod</value>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>

                <!--embedded tomcat server (needed to run tests)-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Code coverage plugin -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <!--
                                Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                                is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
                            -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                    <destFile>${jacoco.ut.execution.data.file}</destFile>
                                    <!--
                                        Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                                        for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                                    -->
                                    <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <!--
                                Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after
                                unit tests have been run.
                            -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>post-unit-test</id>

                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                    <dataFile>${jacoco.ut.execution.data.file}</dataFile>
                                    <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <!--
                                Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                                is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed.
                            -->

                        </executions>

                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- this dependency is only needed to fix a bug in open jdk 8 (test)-->
                            <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                            <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>

            </build>

        </profile>
```

First run commands in this order 
mvn clean
mvn test
mvn jacoco:report

after running the command mvn test, jacoco generates the file containing the information about coverage correctly in the position specified by the property "jacoco.ut.execution.data.file"

but when i run the command mvn jacoco:report i get this error

> --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.2:report (default-cli) @ springbootseed ---
>   Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.

I tried to remove the line

```
<destFile>${jacoco.ut.execution.data.file}</destFile>
```

from the configuration of the prepare agent execution and in this way jacoco writes the file in the default location (target/jacoco.exec)

With this setup jacoco picks the file correctly and generates the report in the default location (site/jacoco).

For those reasons I think jacoco is not picking the configuration form the pom when I run mvn jacoco:report

how can I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the 'argLine' just a maven property and remove from surefire and jacoco plugin as mentioned here : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+SonarJava. It worked for me.